# Convolution formulation with central element of the Kernel matrix is superimposed on the pixel

Tags: computer-vision, convolution

Suppose we perform the convolution operation with a Kernel of odd size. Suppose that the central element of the Kernel matrix is superimposed on the p-th pixel of the image being processed.

Suppose:

- a represents the number of rows of the Kernel matrix
- b represents the number of columns of the Kernel matrix

Then the convolution formula should be as follows:

$$s(i, j)=I(i, j) \otimes f(i, j)=\sum_{m=-\lfloor a / 2\rfloor}^{\lfloor a / 2\rfloor} \sum_{n=-\lfloor b / 2\rfloor}^{\lfloor b / 2\rfloor} I(i-m, j-n) K(m, n)$$

I have looked at many books and many articles, and they all show this formula or read variations representing the same concept.

Problem: With this formula, the Kernel matrix $K$ will have negative indices. Some parts talk about how in this way the kernel is centered, and its central element will have coordinates (0,0).

But this makes no sense mathematically, if I have a 3x3 Kernel, the centre element has coordinate (1,1), not (0,0). What does it actually mean to centre the Kernel matrix? How do I avoid negative indexes? What is a strict formula, which allows to represent the convolution with the central element of the Kernel superimposed on the p-th pixel processed?

Comment: An elegant way to avoid problems like this is to border all matrices by rows and columns of zeros.  This makes mathematical sense and does not alter the convolution.  It's also a great computing solution, too, because it avoids testing special cases near the edges.

Comment: This is generally handled with *padding*. One example is to pad the image with 0s outside its domain. Note that this is equivalent to disregarding convolution elements outside the image domain. Another example is to make cyclic boundary conditions.

Comment: If I know this, I wanted to understand in this specific case, without adding zeros to the edges, what it means to center the Kernel matrix thus having negative indices. I cannot understand this passage mathematically.

Comment: Bordering (or "padding") the edges with zeros and having negative indices are perfectly well-defined mathematically, which makes it difficult to understand what you are trying to ask.

Comment: this is exactly what I cannot understand, the negative indices for matrices

Comment: A matrix is defined as a map $I\times J\to F$ where $I$ and $J$ are index sets (which may include negative numbers) and $F$ is a set of possible matrix entries. *E.g.*, the matrix $\pmatrix{1&2&3\\4&5&6}$ represents a map of two variables $i\in\{1,2,3\},$ $j\in\{1,2,3\}$ sending $(1,1)$ to $1,$ $(1,2)$ to $2,...$ and $(2,3)$ to $6.$ The values in the index sets are irrelevant--that's why computer languages can differ concerning whether to start indexing at $0$ or $1,$ for instance. Indeed, [Fortran allows negative indexes.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran_95_language_features#Arrays)

Comment: That's fine, but how do I convert the positive indices of the Kernel matrix into negative indices? That is, how do I work out which negative index according to the formula is associated with which position in relation to the actual positive indexes?